# Angular UI Router reset $scope

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a quiz using AngularJS and UI Router.

I have my app structured like this:

```
 - intro screen
 - app screen (where you play the actual quiz)
 - results screen (where i display the score)
```

The app use the same controller (MainCTRL). I store in the MainCTRL in `$scope.score` the score.

The problem is that when I `$state.go('results');` the controller is being reseted I think and the `$scope.score` is equal to 0.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controllers are not singletons, they are instantiated every time you use them in `ng-controller`.
If you want to share state between controllers, create a service for that.

```
angular.module('yourModule')
    .service('ScoreService', ScoreService);

// If you want to use dependencies, you can inject them like that
ScoreService.$inject = ['dep1', 'dep2'];

function ScoreService(dep1, dep2) {
    var self = this;
    var score = 0;

    self.getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    self.setScore(value) {
        score = value;
    }

    // Other logic

    return self;
}
```

Inject that service into your controller and use it to get and modify score state.